# My pi 2 doesn't fit into my B+ case

Tags: pi-2, case, pi-b+

I have a case for my pi B+ that came with it, and I can't seem to make my pi 2 fit into it. The case is the one that comes with [this kit](http://amzn.com/B00LVAFC7Y). I'm only confused because I was made to undestand that the B+ and the Pi 2 were the same shape and cases would be interchangeable. Is this not the case?

My pi 2 was made in P.R.C and my pi B+ was made in the UK if that matters.

Answer (score 5):

Interesting, I have the exact same case and it works. You just need to gently force the Pi in, it is a pain to get it in, and a pain to get it out also.

Comment: Ok. Because the B+ fits in smoothly, without forcing of any kind. I'll try this in the morning.

Answer (score 2):

According to the  [Adafruit site](https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-the-raspberry-pi-2-model-b?view=all#what-to-watch-out-for) "The basic form-factor of the Pi 2 Model B is nearly 100% the same as the Pi model B+ ...This means that 99% of cases designed for the Raspberry Pi Model B+ will work with the Raspberry Pi 2 Model B." You may just be in the 1%.

Having said that you may be able to clearance the case with some sanding etc. to get it to fit. But for under $10 you could pick up one of the new cases designed by the foundation. Without some good quality photos - it is impossible to tell just how much modification will be needed.

Comment: And if $10 is too much... We made our Pi cases out of business card boxes.  We've bought 100's of them at the local printer for about $0.1 each.

Comment: I'm curious. Why 99%?

Comment: @PandaLion98 There is a quote from Adafruit, but having worked as a mechanic for several years even mass produced parts have variations. coupled with that a design decision made for one model may become a bug in subsequent designs.